# QNetworkAccessManager threads never finish

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I know that in version 4.8 each http request gets its own thread to run.
I'm doing a links checker app that does a lot of http requests in a while loop and I notice in the windows task manager that my app is using more than 1600 threads over time and the number never goes down, only up until it crashes the app. (I'm guessing that is the cause.)

My question is, does `QNetworkAccessManager` have an option to use thread pool?
Or does it have an option to clean its threads after it finishes its http request?

This is the main loop:

```
while(!rpm_urlStack->isEmpty())
{
    QString url = rpm_urlStack->top();

    //define the reply
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    rpm_urlStack->pop();

    QString urlForReq(url);

    bool returnVal = true;
    QNetworkRequest request;

    request.setUrl(QUrl(urlForReq));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT.toUtf8());
    request.setRawHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    request.setRawHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
    request.setRawHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

    QEventLoop loop;
    reply = m_networkManager->get(request);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exit();

    if(!loop.isRunning()) {
        loop.exec();
    }

    RequestFinishedHandler(reply);

    // this is how I delete the reply object
    delete reply;
}

RequestFinishedHandler(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if (reply->error() > 0) {
        QNetworkReply::NetworkError networkError = reply->error();
        QString err = reply->errorString();
    } else {
        QVariant vStatusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
        QMutexLocker lock(_pMutex); // _pMutex defined as class member
        char *buffer;
        buffer = getCurrentDateTime();
        QTextStream out(m_file);
        out << buffer << "  " << _sCurrentUrl << "\n";
        lock.unlock();

        if(vStatusCodeV.toInt() == 200) {
            QString ApiResponse;
            QByteArray data;
            data=reply->readAll();
            ApiResponse.append(QString::fromUtf8(data));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `RequestFinishedHandler` function do?

Answer (score 1):

It [appears](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater) that to be effective, the `deleteLater` method must be called from within an event loop, which must regain control of execution to handle garbage collection.

Maybe you should refactor your code to have the event loop replace your while loop. Alternatively,  since you're not using the `finished` slot to process the reply, perhaps you can delete the reply directly at the end of the `RequestFinishedHandler` function.

Comment: its not working im manuly delete the replay object but the threads keep  getting up

Comment: please add the changes you made to your question.